# using strings within janitor tabyl !!! top level

Tags: r, rlang, janitor

I'm trying to use a vector of strings as the column inputs inside the `janitor` function `tabyl`

I know I can convert the string to symbols, then use the `big bang` within dplyr functions like `group_by`

```
stg <- syms(c("gear", "carb"))

mtcars %>% group_by(!!!stg) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

But when I try to apply this same logic to the `janitor` function `tabyl` I get the error:

```
mtcars %>%
  tabyl(!!!stg) %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(rounding = "half up", digits = 0) %>%
  adorn_ns(position = "front")
```

**Can't use `!!!` at top level**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create an expression and `eval`uate

```
library(rlang)
exp1 <- expr(mtcars %>%
              tabyl(!!!stg) %>%
              adorn_pct_formatting(rounding = "half up", digits = 0) %>%
              adorn_ns(position = "front"))
eval_tidy(exp1)
#gear        1        2        3        4        6        8
#    3 3 (300%) 4 (400%) 3 (300%) 5 (500%) 0   (0%) 0   (0%)
#    4 4 (400%) 4 (400%) 0   (0%) 4 (400%) 0   (0%) 0   (0%)
#    5 0   (0%) 2 (200%) 0   (0%) 1 (100%) 1 (100%) 1 (100%)
```